# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am using below mentioned link to import an Excel file in Access.

The file also contains data which is irrelevant so I want to use the something like (like "*ABC*") in VBA.

```
filepath "C:\Datenbank\test_filter.xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "auto-filter", filepath, True, "A4:K"
```

Comment: Please clarify as I'm scratching my head on second sentence: *like ABC*...

Comment: Like is a query which will return's the all the rows containing AbC. So I was looking for something in macro so execute the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A link is a link.

So create a simple *select* query with the linked table as source, apply the filter as you wish, and then use this query for your further processing.

Comment: I hope so there is some script which can be used in order to generate the required result.

Comment: You can use the query GUI designer, that's about it. If this is strange for you, browse for a tutorial.